# How to show a loading indicator before returning NetworkImage?

Tags: flutter

I need to preload a circular progress indicator before returning this

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Center(
      child: Container(
        child: PhotoView(
          imageProvider: NetworkImage('imageUrl')),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

I made it like this but circular progress indicator does not appers.

```
Future<NetworkImage> _getImage() {
    return 
       Future.value(NetworkImage('imageUrl'));
}

FutureBuilder<NetworkImage>(
      future: _getImage(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<NetworkImage> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: Center(
              child: Container(
                child: PhotoView(imageProvider: NetworkImage('imageUrl')),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {return Scaffold(body: kLoading);} // loading indicator
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CachedNetworkImage` instead.

Example:

```dart
CachedNetworkImage(
  placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
  imageUrl: 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
);
```

Full Docs: [CachedNetworkImage](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/cached-images)